# VB.NET VSTO referencing custom task panes from ribbon in multiple windows PowerPoint 2013

Tags: vb.net, vsto, powerpoint-2013

I'm creating a COM add-in for my company in VSTO and am having a problem referencing the correct task pane for each window from the ribbon.

I have a custom task pane which shows/hides different commands on the task pane based on ribbon clicks. When I have 1 document window open this works fine, but when I have multiple document windows open the ribbon controls the custom task pane on the final window opened only, not on the active window.

My code (simplified) is

```
Private Sub Agenda_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Agenda.Click

    With Globals.ThisAddIn.AddIn_TP
        .Width = 300
        .Visible = True
    End With

    With Globals.ThisAddIn.AddIn_control1
        With .Panel_table
            .Visible = False
            .Left = 400
        End With
        With .Panel_SummaryBox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = 5
        End With
    End with

End Sub
```

I know that I need to somehow reference the active window and linked taskpane but I don't know how to make this work.

In terms of loading the taskpane, I have code that is called each time a presentation is opened/created, which loads the taskpane for that window. The code is:

```
Private Sub Application_AfterNewPresentation(Pres As PowerPoint.Presentation) Handles Application.AfterNewPresentation

        AddIn_control1 = New AddIn_control
        AddIn_taskpane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(AddIn_control1, "Add-In Taskpane", Me.Application.ActiveWindow)

    End Sub
```

This is working fine, and the taskpane is visible in the new window. However, if I then go back to a previous window and click the ribbon button, it changes the taskpane on the new window, not the active window.

Comment: Can you explain better, what is the relations between taskpanes and windows? Do you have a taskpane for every window or only one taskpane?  Can you show the code that get access to a wrong window?

Comment: I have added some code in to try to explain the relationship - I have read about creating a wrapper which links taskpanes to windows, and found information for doing this in outlook, however I don't understand how to apply that to powerpoint